# Is this the good class design practice in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public class OneClass {
        private AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass();

        private void doOneJob(){
            anotherClass.doOtherJob();
        }
    }
```

In the above code, AnotherClass is instantiated and held as a class variable of OneClass.

- What are the consequences of this design?
- Is it a good practice?
- Will this support unit testing?

Comment: Did you mean adapter pattern?

Answer (score 4):

This is called **composition** and is a fundamental part of Java language. There is nothing wrong with it, and might be essential in a lot of cases.

The only change I would do is use dependency injection to make it easier for testing, i.e. you'll be able to supply a mock `AnotherClass` object this way:-

```
public class OneClass {
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

    public OneClass(AnotherClass anotherClass){
        this.anotherClass = anotherClass;
    }

    private void doOneJob() {
        anotherClass.doOtherJob();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The dependency injection looks good. However, I have a native lib call in AnotherClass.java. I guess the dependency injection takes care of this native lib if I can successfully mock AnotherClass.java.

Comment: Yes, native methods can be overridden just like other methods except if they are final. You should create an interface and give separate implementations of this method in the implementing classes. And use the interface in `OneClass`.

Comment: To be more specific the pattern could be either composition or aggregation, depending by the innerObj. existence ( just inside wrapper object or even outside as "stand-alone" object)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to "unit" testing because you cant mock the "external" dependency in a normal way. (With groovy tests for example you can override private fields with a mock)

I think it would be better that you have a constructor that accepts a `AnotherClass` than you can mock it in a unit test via constructor.